# In the notation $T\colon\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^m$, does $\mathbb{R}^m$ refer to the codomain or the image of $T$?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, vectors, terminology, transformation

### Question:

It is my understanding that the term `codomain` refers to a set, of which the `image` is a subset (although, not necessarily a *proper* subset).

However, when speaking of vector transformations using notation like "$T\colon\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^m$",

1. am I correct in understanding that $\mathbb{R}^m$ refers to the codomain, not the image?
2. in the case of vector transformations, is it appropriate to speak of the image as a `subspace` of the codomain (*Vs.* a `subset`)?

Apologies in advance for asking two questions, but given that the first is basically yes/no, I figured it was okay.

---

**My Work** (Thoughts)

I am fairly certain that the image of a *linear* transformations is a subspace of its codomain, because, in that case, the transformation has a matrix representation

$$\boldsymbol{M} \, \in \, \mathbb{M}_{{\color{red}m}\times n}(\mathbb{R}),$$

and $\textrm{Im}\{\boldsymbol{M}\}$ is, in general, a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\color{red}m}$; however, I'm always wary of assuming the language can cross over (*i.e.* from the matrix to the transformation, in this case).

Moreover, based on the little I know about non-linear transformations, I would not expect their images to define a subspace. As such, I would assume that the term `subset` should always be used when describing the general relationship between the image and codomain.

---

**Background / Level**

Aside from real-valued functions and the usual fare seen in vector-calculus, I have no real experience with non-linear vector transformations. I have also never properly understood the importance of the distinction between image and codomain.

Comment: Indeed, for a map $f\colon V\to W$ between vector spaces, $W$ is the codomain which is not necessarily the range of $f$. We denote the range/image of $f$ by $\operatorname{Im}f$ which is a subset of $W$ which is not a subspace of $W$ in general (it is a subspace when the map $f$ is linear). +1 for a good post btw! :)

Comment: 1. Yes, you're correct. 2. It is true that if $T:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is a linear transformation then the image of $T$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: This isn't relevant to your question, but since I enjoy little TeX distinctions here you go.  Generally for function definitions you want to use `\colon` rather than `:` because it gets the spacing right, so I changed `T : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^m` $T : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^m$ to `T\colon\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^m` $T\colon\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^m$.  See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37789/using-colon-or-in-formulas).

Comment: @PrasunBiswas thanks for the comment & upvote, much appreciated!

Comment: @DMcMor - thank you *so much* for taking the time to share that one. I have long hated the handling of `:` for definitions and probably would not have discovered this, on my own. Are you aware of any similar solutions for `\in`? I always find expressions like $\{ x \colon x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ to look a bit crowded (although my public is generally very new to such notation, so I may be too fussy about it).

Comment: @RaxAdaam, for that one you do actually want to use `:`, or `\mid`, so it looks like either $\lbrace x : x\in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$ or $\lbrace x \mid x\in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$.  IMO that also makes the spacing around `\in` a bit less out of place.

Comment: @DMcMor -- interesting, this could be a platform issue, actually. Normally I end up with something more like $\{$$x\colon$ $x$$\in$$\mathbb{R}$$\}$, all smashed together, and have to add `\,` before and after `\in` to get something spaced appropriately, but the rendering here is perfect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that $\mathbb{R}^m$ is the codomain of this map $T$. However, lets explore the roots of your confusion as noted at the end of your question.

The *image* of $T$ is defined as $T(\mathbb{R}^n) := \{T(x): x \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$. As you can see, this is a subset (and if $T$ is linear, also a subspace ${}^\dagger$) of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and is read as "the set of all those $T(x)$ such that $x$ lies in $\mathbb{R}^n$". This set certainly can be equal to the whole codomain if $T$ is a *surjective* map, *i.e* $T(\mathbb{R}^n) = \mathbb{R}^m$. If $T$ is not surjective, then there is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ who is not the image of some vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Note, we can adapt this notion of the *image of a set* to subsets of the domain: *e.g.*, let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then the image of $A$ is $T(A) := \{T(x): x \in A\}$.

**Note:** It is common to see other notations to denote the image of a map such as $im \ T$ or rather uncommonly, the name of the map will appear as subscript to aide in specifying the image of a particular set (with respect to $T$): $im_{T}(A)$.

---

${}^\dagger$ *Proof that if $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $T$ is a linear transformation, $T(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$*.

Suppose that $w_1, w_2 \in T(A)$. Then, by definition of $T(A)$ there exists $u_1, u_2 \in A$ such that $w_{1} := T(u_{1})$ and $w_{2} := T(u_{2})$. Now, we want to show that $T(A)$ is closed under linear combinations; consider the linear combination $\alpha w_{1} + \beta w_{2}$ where  $\alpha, \beta$ are scalers. Therefore we can compute: $$\begin{align*} \alpha w_{1} + \beta w_{2} &= \alpha T(u_1) + \beta T(u_2) \\ &= T(\alpha u_1) + T(\beta u_2) \ \ \ by \ the \ linearity \ of \ T \\ &= T(\alpha u_1 + \beta u_2) \ \ \ again \ by \ the \ linearity \ of \ T.    \end{align*}$$ So since $A$ is a subspace, $u_{1}, u_2 \in A \implies \alpha u_1 + \beta u_2 \in A.$ Thus,  $\alpha w_{1} + \beta w_{2} \in T(A)$, since it is the image of the vector $\alpha u_1 + \beta u_2 \in A$. So $T(A)$ is closed under linear combinations and hence is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: "As you can see, this is a subset (and subspace) of $\mathbb{R}^m$ ..." In fact, it is _not_ obvious to me that this subset is, in general, a subspace (this is more or less what I am asking in the question). Given the closure conditions for subspaces, it's not clear to me how one would show that the Image is a subspace, in general. Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge and understanding!

Comment: Ah, the words I always try to avoid (“*as you can see*, obviously.. etc*) have slipped my tongue! I apologize for that. You’re welcome though, always happy to help! I will edit my answer and add a short proof as to why the image of a subset is a subspace of the codomain. @RaxAdaam

Comment: A challenge I am always working on, as well! "As I can see..." just doesn't have the same camaraderie :D

Comment: @RaxAdaam just added a small proof to show $T(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Please do not hesitate to ask questions!

Comment: Thanks for the update -- but isn't this just for the case that $T$ is linear? My question was about vector transformations _in general_, not _linear_ vector transformations. Sorry if I am missing something obvious -- it happens far too often!

Comment: @RaxAdaam - if $T$ is **not** linear then you cannot perform the operations needed to show that the vector $\alpha w_{1} + \beta w_{2}$ is in $T(A)$, hence we cannot show that $T(A)$ is a subspace.